# Visual Studio 2015 debug visualizer changes

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-debugging, debuggervisualizer

I am trying to use [EnumerableDebugVisualizer](https://rapiddevbookcode.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=EnumerableDebugVisualizer) and [List Visualizer](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25268/A-Generic-List-and-Dictionary-Debugger-Visualizer) unfortunately none of them has a build for Visual Studio 2015.

I tried using the DLLs provided which are for VS 2013 and VS 2010 and both of them error with the following message type when trying to visualize:

> Unable to load the custom visualizer.
>
> Additional information: The UI-side visualizer type
>   'ListVisualizer.DebuggerSide' must derive from
>   'Microsoft.VisualStudio.DebuggerVisualizers.DialogDebuggerVisualizer'.

I decompiled the DLLs or executables with dotPeek and both of the visualizers do derive from `Microsoft.VisualStudio.DebuggerVisualizers.DialogDebuggerVisualizer` so I don't know what exactly is the cause of the error.

Any ideas on how to get them to work with Visual Studio 2015?

Comment: Most likely the `Microsoft.VisualStudio.DebuggerVisualizers.dll` assembly of VS2013 has a different assembly version than the one of VS2015, Thus, while the types have identical "names" they have different versions - something might not be visible in error messages (dotPeek should help find that out though). If that is the case, the visualizer in question would need to be rebuild for VS2015 (using its version of `Microsoft.VisualStudio.DebuggerVisualizers.dll`).

Comment: That might be it, I will give it a check later and tell you how it goes.

Answer (score 2):

Visual Studio 2015 is version 14, so make sure you're referencing the `Microsoft.VisualStudio.DebuggerVisualizers.dll` from:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\v2.0

[image]

Comment: Visual Studio 2017 has changed to version 15. This helped me and might help someone else looking for the solution if their older visualizers no longer work.

Comment: This solved my issue, thanks.  I had pulled in the version for VS 2017 via the nuget package which said it would work with VS2012+

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the %VSINSTALLDIR%\Common7\Packages\Debugger\Visualizers directory? I mean ...Program Files...\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\Packages\Debugger\Visualizers. Probably you can find the dll there.

or

Install the NuGet Package

$Install-Package VSSDK.DebuggerVisualizers.10

Let us know.

Comment: Not an answer: I already mentioned in the question that this does not work.

Comment: Yes. but the NuGet Package VSSDK.DebuggerVisualizers.10 is for VS 2015 as well. Have you tried it ?